# How to get value from inside quotation marks in HTML using Java and Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

[image]

Of course I can get a link using command

```
System.out.print(link.getText());
```

but in this case I will only get value "Saab". I need to have date and image size that are inside quotation marks as well.

Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

complete html could have helped us to give you a better answer.

This will give - `Saab <Date> <size>`

`System.out.print(link.findElement(By.xpath("./..")).getText());`

Basically I am trying to get the parent element of the link and get the complete innerText.

Comment: @Tomas glad that it helped